# I m trying to do dynamically solve this problem but it throwing error....what should I change?

Tags: java

## Declared a function

#### in function I have initialize a double array to store the previous iteration data.

Mainly the problem is in the initialization of memo[0] and memo[1]. When I try to get the result of this 2 specific place, it throw index out of bound error ###

```
static double  fdyn(int n)
    {
         double[] memo;
         memo = new double[n+1];
         memo[0] = 1.0;
         memo[1] = 2.0;
         memo[2] = 4.0;
         for(int i = 3; i<= n;i++)
         {
            memo[i] = (memo[i-1] + memo[i-2]) * memo[i-3];
         } 
         return memo[n];
    }
```

## Main function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.print("Value: ");
        int value = sc.nextInt();
      
        System.out.print("fdyn("+value+") = ");
        System.out.println ( fdyn(value) );
        
      }
```

### But throwing this error for value 0 and 1

```
Value: 0
fdyn(0) = Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        at recursive.fdyn(recursive.java:33)
        at recursive.main(recursive.java:55)
PS C:\Users\looka\OneDrive\Documents\EOCS\JAVA_ASSIGNMENT_Q_ANS\Java_code>
```

### For other values it is perfectly working such as value 2,3,4

```
Value: 3
fdyn(3) = 0.0

Value: 4
fdyn(4) = 8.0

Value: 2
fdyn(2) = 4.0
```

Comment: you can use some debugging to solve your issue and it doesn't need StackOverflow I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize `memo[2]` if `memo` only has two items. Likewise, you can't initialize `memo[1]` if `memo` only has one item.

```java
static double  fdyn(int n)
    {
         double[] memo;
         memo = new double[n+1];
         memo[0] = 1.0;
         memo[1] = 2.0; // this line is problematic if n == 0
         memo[2] = 4.0; // this line is problematic if n == 1
         for(int i = 3; i<= n;i++)
         {
            memo[i] = (memo[i-1] + memo[i-2]) * memo[i-3];
         } 
         return memo[n];
    }
```

The solution would be to take those special cases into account:

```java
static double  fdyn(int n)
    {
         if (n == 0)
             return 1.0;
         if (n == 1)
             return 2.0;
         if (n == 2)
             return 4.0;
         double[] memo;
         memo = new double[n+1];

         memo[0] = 1.0;
         memo[1] = 2.0; 
         memo[2] = 4.0; 
         for(int i = 3; i<= n;i++)
         {
            memo[i] = (memo[i-1] + memo[i-2]) * memo[i-3];
         } 
         return memo[n];
    }
```